# VLOOKUP with if statement (get price based of id)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Currently, I have a single sheet which contains: ID, ProductName, Price

I need help with the formula so that in another tab (Google Sheets) the way to get a price based on ID(or product name)

if I select for example A1 and will change product ID in the formula, it will display the product price based on this ID (or product name)

Comment: The question here is unclear - are you unaware of how to use `VLOOKUP`, or do you not know if you are given the ProductName or the ID?  (Then use `IFERROR` to check one, and then the other - e.g. `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ID, etc), VLOOKUP(Name, etc))`)

Comment: @Chronocidal have amended the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need it for range use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A; Sheet1!A:C; 3; 0); 
                              VLOOKUP(A1:A; Sheet1!B:C; 2; 0))))
```

Comment: it checks range A1:A for your input. if input is found in column A in sheet1 it returns column C from sheet1. if it doesnt find a value in A column of sheet1 it checks column B in sheet1 and returns column C. if no value is found it returns nothing. in other words in range A1:A of your 2nd sheet you can either input valid values of column A or column B of sheet1 and if found it will return you column C of sheet1

Answer (score 0):

If you look up [`VLOOKUP` on Microsoft Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), you will see that it gives several examples of how to use `VLOOKUP` for a value.

Example 5 seems the closest to what you want (i.e. "If the ID cannot be found, return something else") - but instead of just saying "Product Not Found", you want to use **another** `VLOOKUP` to compare the Product Name instead.  To simplify, I will use the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1; 'Products And Prices'!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); VLOOKUP(A1; 'Products And Prices'!$B:$C; 2; FALSE))
```

An important thing here is that final `; FALSE`, to ensure that we get an error if the value is not found (instead of just returning the "best fit")